# General terms for the following infinite sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

$$S_1 = \{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}=1,\; \frac 32, \;\frac 74, \;\frac {15}8,\cdots$$
$$S_2 = \{b_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}=5,\; \frac 72,\; \frac {11}4,\;\frac  {19}8,\cdots$$

How do I find the general term, i.e. $a_n,b_n$, for each sequence?

Many thanks.

Comment: Like $S1_n = \frac{2^n - 1}{2^{n-1}}$ and you can figure out S2 on the same lines ?

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your post.  You had used $a_n$ for both sequences, and I thought it was clearer to use $a_n$ for the first and $b_n$ for the second.  If you prefer it the original way, click on edit and change it back.  Or add a comment and I'll change it back.

Comment: Where are "the following infinite sequences"?

Comment: For $S1$, compute $2-a_n$ for each $n$ and a familiar pattern emerges...

Comment: For $S_2$, compute $a_n-2$ for each $n$ and another familiar pattern emerges...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know [geometric progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)? Then try "easier" questions:

- Find the pattern in $1,2,4,8,\cdots$
- Find the pattern in $1,3,7,15,\cdots$
- Find the pattern in $5,7, 11, 19,\cdots$

For the second and third ones, try to see how they related to the first one.

Now combine everything together.

Comment: My usual reply to such questions is “what's the number following $5$, $10$, $20$, $30$, $36$”?

Comment: @egreg: I like your comment a lot. That would be more *concrete* than "find the pattern".

Comment: @egreg - what an interesting sequence :) Mozart would have been pleased.